# Display button show less in click button show more in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, events

I added button "show less " after click on button "show more ". The problem, the button shows less is displayed in current div and other that it have button show more .How I can display it only in div that it have button show more clicked.

```
     <?php
    if ($custom_term->count > 2) {
                echo ("<div class='dedcription-btn pop recrut act show-more' cat-posts='$custom_term->count'  data-id='$current_category'>
                <span class='name-descripeion ' >Show more  \"$custom_term->name\"</span>
                <div class='btn-icon'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i></div>
            </div>  ");

           
                echo (" <div class='dedcription-btn pop recrut act show-less '>
                <span class='name-descripeion  '>Show less</span>
                <div class='btn-icon'>
                    <i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
                </div>
            </div>  ");
           
          
            }
   
   ?>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

                 $('.show-less').hide();

                $(".show-more").click(function(e){
                    
                $('.show-block').toggleClass('show-block hide-block').toggle(); 
                $(this).prev().find('.hide-block').slice(0,4).toggleClass('hide-block show-block').css({"display": "block", visibility:'visible'});

                $('.show-less').show();
                
                });

                        $(".show-less").click(function(){
                        $('.show-block').toggleClass('show-block hide-block').toggle(); 

                        $('.show-more').show();
                        $('.show-less').toggleClass('center-bottons');
                        $(this).hide();
                    });

});
   </script>
```

Comment: could you please explain a little better your issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The button show less should be appear in block that his button show more is clicked not for all block they have button show more.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.show-less').hide();

  $(".show-more").click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest(".full-post").find(".hide-block").fadeIn();
    $(this).closest(".full-post").find(".show-less").show();
  });

  $(".show-less").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).closest(".full-post").find(".hide-block").fadeOut();
    $(this).closest(".full-post").find(".show-more").show();
  });

});
```

```css
.hide-block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-post">
  <div class="show-block">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut. Volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit. Lacus sed viverra tellus in hac. Habitasse
      platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Sed odio morbi quis commodo
      odio aenean. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna. Pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Dictum varius duis at consectetur
      lorem donec massa sapien faucibus. Sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu. Suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed. Malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hide-block">
    <p>
      Quam quisque id diam vel quam. Nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae. Sit amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Sed
      vulputate odio ut enim blandit. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam. Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Orci a scelerisque purus semper. Enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque
      sit.
    </p>
    <p>Sed vulputate mi sit amet mauris commodo. Nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices. Mi proin sed libero enim sed faucibus. Rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. A lacus vestibulum
      sed arcu non odio euismod. Etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus
      non. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci
      nulla pellentesque. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='dedcription-btn pop recrut act show-more' cat-posts='10' data-id='cat-01'>
    <span class='name-descripeion '>Show more</span>
    <div class='btn-icon'> <i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i></div>
  </div>
  <div class='dedcription-btn pop recrut act show-less '>
    <span class='name-descripeion'>Show less</span>
    <div class='btn-icon'>
      <i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since each `click` is specific, we can be specific in our code, instead of using toggle function. We know "Show More" will expand the hidden items and "Show Less" will always collapse the hidden items.

Placing each inside the same wrapper as the items allows us to select the proper items relative to the "Show More" and "Show Less".